# union for collections.Set

Tags: python, collections, set

I define my own set class using `collections.Set`:

```
class MySet(collections.Set):
    def __init__(self, data=frozenset()):
        self._set = frozenset(data)
    __len__ = lambda self: self._set.__len__()
    __iter__ = lambda self: self._set.__iter__()
    __contains__ = lambda self: self._set.__contains__()
```

I wish to inherit the `frozenset.union` method. With that method you can do the following:

```
>>> frozenset.union(frozenset('ab'), frozenset('bc'))
frozenset(['a', 'c', 'b'])
>>> frozenset.union(*[frozenset('ab'), frozenset('bc')])
frozenset(['a', 'c', 'b'])
```

I want to be able to do the following:

```
>>> MySet.union(MySet('ab'), MySet('bc'))
MySet(['a', 'c', 'b'])
>>> MySet.union(*[MySet('ab'), MySet('bc')])
MySet(['a', 'c', 'b'])
```

How do I best go about this?

Comment: "I define my own set class using collections.Set", [Why?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I have reduced my own particular set class down to the above for this question. The particular class adds functionality to this class different from the one in the built-in (frozen)set, but those aspects are irrelevant to this question; i.e., I've omitted the unnecessary aspects to create a minimal example.

Comment: EDIT: clarified exactly what I want to do, i.e., illustrated `frozenset.union` and hypothetical `MySet.union`

Answer (score 1):

You have `__or__` which is called when you write `s1 | s2` and is supposed to mean the union of two sets.

Comment: I am specifically interested in inheriting/emulating the `frozenset.union` method which allows taking the union of arbitrary numbers of frozensets

Comment: I have to define `__or__ = lambda self, other: MySet(self._set | other._set)`, otherwise `TypeError: specify a Set instead of a generator`, because I have `if isinstance(data, Set):` before guarding the equivalent of `self._set = frozenset(data)` in my particular case

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say this is the "best way", but could work for your personal use?

```
import collections

class MySet(collections.Set):
    def __init__(self, data=frozenset()):
        self._set = frozenset(data)
    __len__ = lambda self: self._set.__len__()
    __iter__ = lambda self: self._set.__iter__()
    __contains__ = lambda self: self._set.__contains__()
    __union__ = lambda self,j: self._set.union(j)

a = MySet(range(5))
b = MySet(range(3,10))

print a.__union__(b)
print b.__union__(a)

"""
>>>
frozenset([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
frozenset([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>>
"""
```

Comment: If I say `union = lambda self, other: MySet(self._set.union(other))`, then I get: `MySet().union(MySet(set('ab')))` gives `MySet(frozenset(['a', 'b']))` and `MySet.union(MySet(set('ab')))` gives `TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`